# Translate dataframe with DeepL

Tags: python, translate, deepl

I would like to translate (using DeepL) the text inside the df ["text"] column, where in each line there is a sentence.
The text is not written in a single language, so I'd like to automatically detect the language of the text and put the translation in a new column called df ["translated"].

Thank you

I have DeepL's free authentication key but I can't figure out how to use it, I am a rookie.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [DeepL-Python library](https://github.com/DeepLcom/deepl-python).

According to the [documentation](https://www.deepl.com/de/docs-api/translating-text/request/) you can just ommit the parameter `source_lang` and it will try to detect the language by its own.

```
import deepl
translator = deepl.Translator(auth_key)
result = translator.translate_text(text_to_translate)
translated_text = result.text
```

Answer (score 5):

I needed to translate a column in a dataframe for a recent project, and thought I would share my approach using DeepL's [Python client library](https://github.com/DeepLcom/deepl-python) in case it's helpful.

```
import pandas as pd
import deepl
translator = deepl.Translator(auth_key)

d = {'Source': ['This is some English source text.', 'Another sentence in English.']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df['Target'] = df['Source'].apply(lambda x: translator.translate_text(x,  
               target_lang="DE") if type(x) == str else x)
```

As mentioned above, the `source_lang` argument can be omitted if you'd like DeepL to auto-detect source language—that's what I do here.

You'll end up with:

```
    Source                              Target
0   'This is some English source text.' 'Dies ist ein englischer Ausgangstext.'
1   'Another sentence in English.'      'Ein weiterer Satz auf Englisch.'
```

(The `if type(x) == str else x` isn't necessary, but could be helpful in case you have null or other non-string values in your source text column that you'd rather just skip over.)

Answer (score 0):

I can't test it because I don't have a API key, but by reading the documentation of the  [free Deepl API](https://www.deepl.com/fr/docs-api/translating-text/request/), everything is well indicated, with a CURL example:

```
curl https://api.deepl.com/v2/translate \
    -d auth_key=[yourAuthKey] \
    -d "text=Hello, world!"  \
    -d "target_lang=DE"
```

The documentation indicates that the `source_lang` parameter is optional and if it is omitted, the API will attempt to detect the language of the text and translate it.

So in python code, it should be

```py
import requests
import json
url = "https://api-free.deepl.com/v2/translate"
data = f"auth_key={yourAuthKey}&text={YourText}&target_lang={LanguageCode}"
resp = requests.post(url, data=data)
translated_text = json.loads(resp.content)
print(translated_text)
```

with:

- `yourAuthKey` - your API key.
- `YourText` - the text you wish to translate.
- `LanguageCode` - the language code (see API doc) into which the text should be translated.

It should be fine like this with standard libraries.

Or you can use official [DeepL Python Library](https://github.com/DeepLcom/deepl-python) to make it even simpler.